# adding two blank lines in the last of each text file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a few text files and need to add two extra blank lines in the last of each file. Following script adds one blank line (with one space) in the last of each text file. How to add one more blank line? Thanks a lot in advance.

```
  import glob
  for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):
      with open(file, "a") as f:
          f.write(" ")
          f.write(" ")
          f.close()
```

Comment: You are not writing a blank line, you are writing a line with a space. Try `f.write('\n\n')`.

Comment: This - `f.write("\n")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`f.write()` does not automatically add a newline to your files, you have to add the newline yourself.

Also, you do not need to do `f.close()` , that is handled by the `with` statement.

Example -

```
import glob
for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    with open(file, "a") as f:
        f.write("\n\n")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just print new line characters:

```
 import glob
  for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):
      with open(file, "a") as f:
          f.write("\n\n")
```

When you're using the `with` statement, you don't have to close file manually. Python will do this for you.